# Install cloudbase-init msi package on to mounted vhd file

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-installer, vhd, setup.exe

I m trying to install cloudbse-init.msi setup file from powershell or from command line to install on a offline drive or vhd file mounted on to machine.

I have used following command but it does not install on vhd file.

```
msiexec /qb /l* l.txt /i <path>\CloudbaseInitSetup_Beta.msi TARGETDIR="F:\Program Files (x86)"
```

Where F: drive is a mounted virtual drive.

Please let me know how to install a msi file on to a offline vhd image.

Comment: This isnt really a PowerShell specific question.

Comment: yup but can execute the statement above on powershell as well right.

Comment: you could :) what i meant was you probably more likely to get help with someone with msiexec skills than you are from a PowerShell expert.

Comment: yup will remove the tag ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your msiexec commandline has the wrong order. 
The parameter "/i" followed by the .msi file has to be first. Like this:

```
msiexec /i "<path>\CloudbaseInitSetup_Beta.msi" /qb /l* "<path>l.txt" TARGETDIR="F:\Program Files (x86)"
```

Don't forget the double quotes for all three parameters containing path values. Furthermore, if your msi file needs elevated rights, which is normally needed, when installing to one of the "Program Files.." directories, you have to specify **full pathes**, because you loose the current directory during elevation.

So writing "/i .\mydir\my.msi" would be a bad idea, because this is a relative path.